# Finding a permutation

Tags: algorithms

it's my first time here. I have an algorithmic problem. My friend said it's trivial, but I can't make it out.
So, I'm given a multiset, like this one: $$\{1\rightarrow2; 2\rightarrow1; 3\rightarrow2; 4\rightarrow 3\}$$

First number means a particular number, second means how many of them are there.
I'm also given two numbers $p$ and $q$ for example $4$ and $1$. My task is to find a permutation of this set which will start with $p$ and end with $q$ and all adjacent elements won't be equal.
In this example, one of the answers would be: $$\{4,1,4,3,4,2,3,1\}$$

I've come up with an algorithm but in some cases it ends up in a dead end. I'd be very glad if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to find the permutation on the middle digits 4abcdef1. What remains are {1→1;2→1;3→2;4→2}.

So if you put the rest of the 4's, that would be C(6,4). Then, put all the 3's, that's C(4,2). Then, put the lone 2, that would be C(2,1).

So the total number of possible permutations is C(6,4) * C(4,2) * C(2,1) = 15 * 6 * 2.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I'm looking for a way to generate one of the answers rather than number of permutations.